# Highlight word under cursor for Go channel

Tags: highlight, filetype-go

I use this code to highlight:

```
autocmd CursorMoved * exe printf('match IncSearch /\V\<%s\>/', escape(expand('<cword>'), '/\'))
```

But it fail for `<-done` in Go:

[image: vim go highlight word under cursor]

`:verbose set isk` returns

```
  iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255,-
        Last set from ~/.vim/vimrc line 225
```

Comment: I don't seem to reproduce this issue... What does `:verbose set isk?` tell you while editing this Go source? Please [edit] the question to include this information.

Comment: @filbranden added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ooops, I found that in my vimrc I have

`"set iskeyword+=\-`

I have this for autocompletion of CSS classes like `aaa-bbb-ccc`.

Comment: Do so in a file `~/.vim/ftplugin/css.vim`, then it will apply for CSS files only!

Comment: Oh! And in that file make sure you use `setlocal`, to only affect the current buffer...